# Add spacing between bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web layout based on bootstrap 3. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cptjzkqp/) is a JSFiddle. To enable the layout to be responsive, I have had to adopt a slightly awkward structure (that functionality isn't included, but the code does need to be structured in this way). The end result on all small + sized screens is three information boxes, taking up 4 columns each, in an 80% width container. I have had to structure the boxes like this to allow for some responsive functionality. Anyway, How do I increase the white-space padding in between the boxes?

[image: Boxes]

```
<div class="container PageViews">
  <div class="row Page2 text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4 padded">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn glyphicon-bordered"></span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-bordered"></span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone glyphicon-bordered"></span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 eqheight1">
            <p class>Text 1 </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h3>Title 2</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 eqheight2">
            <p>Text 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h3>Title 3</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 eqheight3">
            <p>Text 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Page2 > *:nth-child(-n+3) {
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.Page2 > *:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.Page2 > * {
  border: 5px solid white;
  background: #3DBEAF;
}
```

Comment: You should post code that reflects your overall structure [mcve] since you have a fairly convoluted one which in turn makes helping you that much more difficult given the lack of useful information.

Comment: @vanburen how could that be any less and still communicate the problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "less", I was not suggesting that you post "less" code. I am referring to the code you posted should demonstrate how it currently functions because a solution to the question **MAY** not be straight forward because the provided code isn't enough to actually see how you have this set up. This should be as simple as adding some margin but doesn't appear be. **Minimal** yes but also **complete**.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses the grid system, where every row is made up of 12 columns. If you would like more padding between the boxes, you have to use fewer columns. You should change `col-sm-4` to `col-sm-3`.

You want to increase the `margin` between boxes not the padding.

I edited your jsfiddle, and this line increased the whitespace between the boxes

```css
.Page2 > *:nth-child(-n+3) {
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.Page2 > *:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.Page2 > * {
  border: 5px solid white;
  background: #3DBEAF;
}

.col-sm-3 {
 margin-right: 8%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container PageViews">
  <div class="row Page2 text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3 padded">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn glyphicon-bordered"></span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-bordered"></span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone glyphicon-bordered"></span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 eqheight1">
            <p class>Text 1 </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h3>Title 2</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 eqheight2">
            <p>Text 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h3>Title 3</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 eqheight3">
            <p>Text 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Click on full page to see the results.

Comment: Thanks! I have suggested an edit to make the boxes central.